# Enthought Canopy for Linux High DPI support?

Tags: enthought, canopy

I'm using the latest version of Enthought Canopy on Linux Mint 17, running on a 11.1 Macbook Pro Retina.
As the title suggests, menus and buttons are painfully minuscule in the editor and Canopy launch window.
Is there any way to increase the size of these so it's more usable? Or is there a fix in the works for it?

Thanks.

Comment: I do not understand what this has to do with python (or programming).

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Canopy is a programming environment

Comment: @TimCastelijns the question is more of a software problem with the retina than with python, in fact the issue has nothing to do with python.

Comment: Sorry for the misleading tag. This is the only way to ask questions about Canopy that I could find on Enthought's website.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Enthought Canopy is a scientific Python IDE plus a Python distribution with 200 scientific packages / libraries. Therefore Stackoverflow has historically been accepted as the appropriate site for Canopy questions. Such questions may range from Python language to package function / design to data analysis / visualization to IDE functioning. This question is one of IDE functioning. --Enthought support.

Comment: @JonathanMarch Heed, he used the "python tag" and he later edited.

Comment: Thanks for the report. We will investigate. --Enthought Support